# standalone database

Tags: .net, database

I'm currently designing a small application in .Net and in the past I've been using MSAccess as standalone database that I can ship with the program. 
But I was wondering if in this day and age there wasn't alternative solutions, as easy to integrate in a .Net app., as transparent for the user and maybe better performance with large amount of data?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your options are:

- [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org)
- [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)
- Sql Server CE - [depricated](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776328/port-sql-compact-to-windows-rt), latest version, [4.0 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709) was released 8/31/2012
- [VistaDB](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/VistaDB) - commercial
- [ESE](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc961824) - Which is hard to integrate with .Net

SQL CE and Firebird are a lot faster when you need multithreaded writes, sqlite is king for single threaded access, or multithreaded reads. VistaDb is 100% managed so you can ship it on embedded devices.

These DBs in general will give you better reliability and performance to access. I would strongly recommend against using any of these dbs over a network share.

Comment: ESE is not hard to intagrate with .NET anymore... You can use ESENT Managed Interop http://www.codeplex.com/ManagedEsent

Comment: managed ese net is still fairly complex to consume compared to the other embedded dbs, it has a great advantage that it ships with windows.

Comment: The link for Sqlite http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ is dead. However that on still works: http://www.sqlite.org. Also they say that SQL CE becomes depreciated. It is not even supported by VS 2013.

Answer (score 9):

SQLite! This is exactly what it was made for.

http://www.sqlite.org/

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  I would recommend [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), which is a ADO.NET wrapper around [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), a popular embedded database written in C.

Answer (score 2):

[VistaDb](http://www.vistadb.net/) is another one

Answer (score 1):

SQLite appears to match your needs -- see [here](http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/) for more.

Answer (score 1):

There is always [SQL Server CE...](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) but I have found SQLite to be much easier to work with, especially with System.Data.Sqlite