# Is there a "best" or most popular database for standalone Java app?

Tags: java, database, desktop

Is there a "best" or more popular database for standalone Java app?
I'm currently writing by hand, but I would like to know what is commonly done, if there is something that is commonly done.

update: talking about small app (may grow, but its small for now)

Comment: possible duplicate of [standalone database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016063/standalone-database)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That was for .Net and this was for Java ;)

Comment: Should be community wiki, no 'one' answer.

Comment: @GeogeStocker agree with community wiki. But about the right answer, if someone wants to know this in 2012, its best ask again, as this will not be so active and up-to-date.. Even if it's still an open question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest using something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) with [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/).

It also sounds like [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) and [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (which ships with certain Java versions) are popular choices.

Comment: I love SQLite - especially for small apps.  It's really easy to embed it and start using a DB.

Comment: Using JavaDB, looks very nice. SQLite look good too, but I find a better tutorial for JavaDB. Choose you as right because you cited both.

Comment: I don't recommend SQLiteJDBC. It has a lot of issues with multi-threading. I almost always get a .db-journal file when using it. I didn't try the others.

Answer (score 9):

Java 6 ships with Derby (renamed [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/)).  It can be used in memory or server mode.

[HyperSQL (HSQLDB)](http://hsqldb.org/) is also popular.

Answer (score 2):

For development purposes, I often use the Hypersonic SQL Database ([HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)). It's fast and lightweight, and good enough to get started.
For a bigger application, I'd go for [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), which supports more options.

Answer (score 1):

The main competitors - HyperSQL (HSQLDB), JavaDB (Derby) and SQLite (not java-based) were mentioned.

There are a few other options:

- [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) - object database
- [FirebirdSQL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) - not java-based.
- [Jackrabit](https://cwiki.apache.org/JCR/embedded-repository.html) - a content repository (not RDBMS) supporting embedded mode.

Answer (score 0):

- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) is a well-established option.
- [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) comes with the development kit

Answer (score 0):

apart all those mentioned here, one can also go for H2 database which is light and can be used in-memory or in server mode.

Answer (score 0):

For a SQL option, you could try MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, or Oracle. Those seem to be the most popular among Java developers.

If you want something NoSQL, MongoDB is the most popular choice with Java developers based on StackOverflow data from 2022.

You can find more information on the metrics used to make that determination in [this article.](https://ashintech.medium.com/5-best-databases-to-use-with-java-a9d3d601daec)