# Database on java for a small project

Tags: java, mysql, database

My software needs to be capable of maintaining and editing a list of employees (with all their personal data like name, cellphone number, adress etc..).

I was wondering what is the best way to go on the employee database side. Should I use MySql? or should I use another technique.

The software needs to be portable and easy to install/use.

Comment: Hi, good question! There was a similar topic. Maybe you can find what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713758/is-there-a-best-or-most-popular-database-for-standalone-java-app

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly use mysql, but there are other options.  As an example, storing data in an xml or json file and using a serialization framework like [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) works for small applications that have limited data types and few if any intersections in their tables.